# How to use prometheus/thanos api: /api/v1/rules param rule_group

Tags: curl, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, thanos

when i use prometheus api to get specify rule group infomation, the api doc as following:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#rules

```
URL query parameters:

type=alert|record: return only the alerting rules (e.g. type=alert) or the recording rules (e.g. type=record). When the parameter is absent or empty, no filtering is done.
rule_name[]=<string>: only return rules with the given rule name. If the parameter is repeated, rules with any of the provided names are returned. If we've filtered out all the rules of a group, the group is not returned. When the parameter is absent or empty, no filtering is done.
rule_group[]=<string>: only return rules with the given rule group name. If the parameter is repeated, rules with any of the provided rule group names are returned. When the parameter is absent or empty, no filtering is done.
file[]=<string>: only return rules with the given filepath. If the parameter is repeated, rules with any of the provided filepaths are returned. When the parameter is absent or empty, no filtering is done.
```

but when i curl the api use following three methods, it all doesn't work!

```
curl -s http://localhost:9090/api/v1/rules?rule_group=ec.rules

curl -s http://localhost:9090/api/v1/rules -d '{"rule_group": "ec.rules"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"

curl -XGET -s 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/rules' --data-urlencode "rule_group=ec.rules" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

curl thanos query is the same result

```
curl -s http://localhost:10902/api/v1/rules?rule_group=ec.rules
```

Anybody know any wrong when i use the curl?Or tell me how to use the prometheus/thanos api? Thanks a lot!

```
prometheus_version: v2.45.0
thanos_version: v0.31.0
```

Comment: My understanding is that Prometheus expects parameter in the form `rule_group[]=ec.rules`, but my limited attempts to use it failed to. Consider filing an issue in [their repository](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues) with detailed explanation what and how you did, and how it failed you (in my tests it returned all rules without filtering, I assume you had the same).

Comment: @markalex same result with you, it will return all rules.

Comment: use `curl localhost:9090/api/v1/rules?rule_group%5B%5D=example.rules` can get the rule with filtering in prometheus!

But can not get rule with filtering from thanos query api. Do you know how to get the same rule info with filtering like prometheus api`curl localhost:9090/api/v1/rules?rule_group%5B%5D=example.rules` in thanos? @markalex

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Thanos at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using latest prometheus version https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.47.2
can get the correct response.
My example:

```
curl -X GET "http://10.136.134.115:9090/api/v1/rules?type=alert&rule_name[]=dingshi"    


{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "node-alerts",
        "file": "/etc/prometheus/rules/rules.yaml",
        "rules": [
          {
            "state": "inactive",
            "name": "dingshi",
            "query": "100 - (node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance=\"10.136.134.240:9100\"} / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=\"10.136.134.240:9100\"} * 100) > 123",
            "duration": 60,
            "keepFiringFor": 0,
            "labels": {
              "severity": "P1"
            },
            "annotations": {
              "description": "test_two",
              "instance": "10.136.134.240",
              "metric": "内存使用率",
              "operator": "gt",
              "threshold": "123"
            },
            "alerts": [],
            "health": "ok",
            "evaluationTime": 0.000517632,
            "lastEvaluation": "2023-11-06T17:51:09.945355348+08:00",
            "type": "alerting"
          }
        ],
        "interval": 60,
        "limit": 0,
        "evaluationTime": 0.001195302,
        "lastEvaluation": "2023-11-06T17:51:09.945345529+08:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```